# Migrate row data into text formatted long multiple

Tags: 8, entities, migrations

I would like to import 3 different row values into a multiple text formatted long field.

This is my migrate (plus) map yml:

```
  ...
  field_mytext_formmated:
    plugin: get
    source:
    - dataValueA
    - dataValueB
    - dataValueC
  ...
```

The data is being migrated but the main problem is that the format property is not being filled so the HTML content is not interpreted.
I don't figure out how to set the format to full_html for all fields.

I've seen that for just one field I should use something like:

```
'body/value': example_matched_field
```

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-process-plugins/migrate-process-overview

But it doesn't seem to work with multiple values.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin named iterator which allows iterate a list of associative fields to a compound field.
Example:
`field_formatted:
      plugin: iterator
      source:
        - fieldA
        - fieldB
      process:
        value: value
        format:
          plugin: default_value
          default_value: 'full_html'`

In this case the fields should have this structure
    `[
      'fieldA' => [
         'value' => 'Chicken',
      ],
    ]`

Can you fields you adapt your source fields to use iterator plugin in this way?

Comment: iterator plugin has been deprecated, instead use sub_process.
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-process-plugins/list-of-core-process-plugins